# VS Code randomly resets back to its default settings

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was coding on my React project and then saved and closed VS Code. a few minutes after opening it I realized that it removed all of my custom settings and reset back to its default settings. I have no idea why this has happened. can someone help me with this, please? are there any measures to prevent this from happening?